# How can i solve Multi-Store Customer Login Error?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, login, customer-account

I have multi store website, store 1 there is no issue, 2nd store getting error while customer login, may i know the possibilities of error?

Note : There is no error in error log files

Comment: Whats the error you are getting when login from 2nd store?

Comment: @SukumarGorai   There is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `System >> Configuration >> Customers >> Customer Configuration >> Share Customer Accounts` , Change this to `Global`.

Comment: My setting same like what you told, still error.